# Module Interdependencies

Tags: linux-kernel, dependencies, kernel, kernel-module

I have 2 modules mod_1.ko & mod_2.ko with fun_1() & fun_2() defined in them respectively. I exported the functions and want to use fun_1 & fun_2 in mod_2.ko & mod_1.ko.   How do I proceed..?

Comment: Go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193532/export-symbol-in-kernel-module-undefined-symbol-during-insmod/17680241#17680241

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using it explicitly (you have call of fun_1 from mod_2.ko and fun_2 from mod_1.ko ) then kernel won't let you load your modules. This is happened because it reads symbol table and look for kernel existing modules - the one you can see in /proc/kallsyms. So mod_1 has fun_2 reference and need mod_2 to be loaded. And mod_2 has fun_1 reference and need mod_1 to be loaded. There you have dependency lock)

I can think of 2 solutions for your problem:

- Take out fun_1 and fun_2 into separate module that you'll load first.
- Don't make explicit call to function. Do this implicitly with help of [`find_symbol`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c?v=3.13#L431). You declare function pointers, then you resolve that pointer in runtime with call to `find_symbol` and then you call your functions via function pointers.

Comment: I figured it out in another way...
I made use of function pointers in one module and registered function in another module with first module's function pointer. Followed the approach of VFS..