# Does kallsyms have all the symbol of kernel functions?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

In the Linux kernel I want to probe the kernel function `effective_prio()`. It defined as `static`.
When I go to search the symbol of it in the *`kallsyms`* I cannot find it. Does *`kallsyms`* have all the symbol of the kernel functions? If not, which symbols are not included?

Comment: I think only exported symbols (those defined with `EXPORT_SYMBOL`, `EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL`, etc.) are listed there.

Comment: No, kallsyms lists all functions, not only exported ones. Actually, it does not know about exported or not exported functions. It distinguishes global functions (marked with 'T' in `/proc/kallsyms`) and local (static) ones, marked with 't'. However, if a function is always inlined or even omitted due to some compiler optimization, perhaps it will not be present in kallsyms at all.

Comment: Have you searched for an exact name? Because, due to some compiler optimizations, for example, the real name of the symbol may also become 'effective_prio.isra.8', or something like that.

Comment: Thank you.But I hasnot seen any symbol like "effective_prio.isra.8".I tried with kernel 3.2 and 3.12.In the source code,You can find the function 'effective_prio' defined in the /kernel/sched.c file.

Comment: Yes, it is not listed in /proc/kallsyms in our ROSA linux system with kernel 3.10 too. AFAIK, it is used in only one place, in [set_user_nice() function](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?v=3.10;i=set_user_nice) and it is static, so it is very likely that the compiler just inlined it into set_user_nice() and did not create an unneeded symbol for it at all. That would explain its absense in kallsyms. What to do next depends on what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5):

There are two possibilities for a function not appearing in `/proc/kallsyms`:

1. If the function is marked as `static`, and the compiler decides to inline the function (with or without the `inline` keyword)
2. If a config option or another `#define` removes a function from being compiled, e.g.:

   ```
   #ifdef CONFIG_OPT
   void foo(void) {
   }
   #endif
   ```

As far as I know, if a function does not appear in `/proc/kallsyms`, it is not possible to call or probe it from a module.
However, `/proc/kallsyms` contains all functions of the kernel, not just the ones exported via `EXPORT_SYMBOL`/`EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL`.

Answer (score 2):

`CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL=y` is also required to see non-static *variables*, e.g.:

```
grep sysctl_sched_nr_migrate /proc/kallsyms
```

which is defined as:

```
const_debug unsigned int sysctl_sched_nr_migrate = 32;
```

Answer (score -1):

kallsyms only lists the symbols exported by EXPORT_SYMBOL and EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL macros.

This is done for security. We don'T usually want modules to be able to access for example internal or security functions. Those just go against the idea of making kernel modules as safe as possible, but allowing them to do as much as it is possible.

Comment: Which commit hardened it so? At least up to kernel 3.10.x, it shows both exported and not exported functions. `/proc/kallsyms` may show 0 as the address of these functions for security reasons when viewed by a non-root user but at least all function names are listed.

Comment: He cannot use nonexported symbols so it is kind of irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, they cannot be used directly in a kernel module, etc. But still, one may need to place a Kprobe on these, for example, for tracing or debugging purposes and so on, so the information about non-exported symbols is sometimes needed. Actually, I did that for debugging.

Comment: As @Eugene commented, this answer is incorrect. kallsysms lists **all** symbols of the kernel image, not just those that are exported.