# Adding dynamic tracepoint through perf in Linux for function that is not listed

Tags: c, linux-kernel, trace, perf

I am trying to trace function `zap_pte_range` from mm/memory.c using *`perf`*. But function is not listed in the `perf probe -F`. So is there a way to dynamically trace this function? I.e. with explicitly adding the tracepoint and recompiling the kernel?

```
perf probe -a zap_pte_range
```

gives:

> [kernel.kallsyms] with build id 33b15ec444475ee7806331034772f61666fa6719 not found, continuing without symbols
>
> Failed to find symbol zap_pte_range in kernel
>
> Error: Failed to add events.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such trace point. So apparently you cannot trace it the easy way. It seems that this function was inlined by compiler (keep in mind that function also could be omitted for some optimization reasons). That's why there is no its symbol in *`/proc/kallsyms`*.

You can choose the most suitable function for you to trace. E.g. in my Debian with 4.9 kernel I can trace [`unmap_page_range()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.9.138/source/mm/memory.c#L1276), which eventually "calls" the function you need. Perhaps it logically will meet your goal.

Another way is a little bit hacking. You can do something like `objdump -dS memory.o | vim -` (you should have binaries) and investigate where is the code you needed. Given that the chain `zap_pud_range()`->`zap_pmd_range()`->`zap_pte_range()` is probably inlined, you will have to investigate aforementioned `unmap_page_range()`. Perhaps you'll finally gain some code address for [*kprobes*](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt).

If you want to explicitly trace `zap_pte_range()` e.g. through *jprobes* (about args) or *kretprobes* (about return value), you can try to specify [`noinline`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474030/how-can-i-tell-gcc-not-to-inline-a-function)-attribute for needed function(s), recompile Linux kernel and trace it as you want.

Guess I have no more useful ways for you.

More info:
[Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196636/does-kallsyms-have-all-the-symbol-of-kernel-functions), [Jprobes example](https://gist.github.com/dzeban/a19c711d6b6b1d72e594), [Ftrace: trace your kernel functions!](https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/03/19/getting-started-with-ftrace/), [Post about ftrace and systemtap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764544/how-to-trace-just-system-call-events-with-ftrace-without-showing-any-other-funct/52775914#52775914), [man nm](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm)